# animated 3d model not rendered correctly xna

Tags: animation, xna, 3d-model, blender-2.67

My animated 3d sheep model(used blender),with a small clip doesnot get rendered correctly,A complete deformed model is rendered, where as my crocodile animated model(also used blender) gets rendered perfectly with the clip played and i had the followed the same steps as of crocodile for sheep.

Here is the link to how it should have been rendered:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/33hb9gar8mqxg2a/toberendered.png

Here is how it is rendered:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bciq6x0f91hb1r/render.png

```
      protected override void LoadContent()
     {
       skin_sheep = sheep.Model.Tag as SkinningData;
        sheep.Transforms = SetupEffectDefaults_anim(sheep.Model);
        player_sheep = new AnimationPlayer(skin);
        clip_sheep = skin_sheep.AnimationClips["ArmatureAction"];
        player_sheep.StartClip(clip_sheep);
       }


       protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
       {
       Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 1000, -1000),new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);


       Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
                                                               GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio,1,1000);`

      `  foreach (ModelMesh mesh in sheep.Model.Meshes)
        {

            foreach (SkinnedEffect effect in mesh.Effects)                      
            {
                effect.SetBoneTransforms(bones_sheep);
                  effect.View = view;
                 effect.Projection = projection;
                effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f);
                effect.SpecularPower = 16;

                effect.World = sheep.Transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                  sheepTransformMatrix;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
       }
```

Please help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: lol@you torrenting things while making screenshots... and half the programs on your desktop are there to deal with viruses. --- Also, can you please zoom in the second ("how it is rendered") screenshot, I can't see anything there. --- Also, please post the code you're rendering it with, and, if possible, the model file. (Assuming it's your own or was acquired legally.)

Comment: I've added zoomed in screenshot and there is probably no virus in my pc i'm fully protected